# How to get fonts into Libre Office Writer

Tags: linux-mint, fonts, cinnamon, libreoffice

I have some fonts on my system that I wish to use in Writer. They are present in the file system, but do not appear in the Libre Office fonts list.

I can see them when I run fc-list

```
$ fc-list | grep -E 'Century|Bitstream'
```

> /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/c0649bt_.pfb: Bitstream Charter:style=Italic
>
> /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/c0633bt_.pfb: Bitstream Charter:style=Bold Italic
>
> /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/c0648bt_.pfb: Bitstream Charter:style=Regular
>
> /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/c059013l.pfb: Century Schoolbook L:style=Roman
>
> /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/c0632bt_.pfb: Bitstream Charter:style=Bold
>
> /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/c059033l.pfb: Century Schoolbook style=Italic
>
> /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/c059016l.pfb: Century> Schoolbook
> L:style=Bold
>
> /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/c059036l.pfb:> Century Schoolbook
> L:style=Bold Italic

Everything I’ve read effectively says ‘It just works if they are under /usr/share/fonts’.

What can I do? The problem has survived several reboots.

Comment: I found this: [LibreOffice drops Type 1 font support](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Blogs/Off-the-Beat-Bruce-Byfield-s-Blog/LibreOffice-drops-Type-1-font-support)

Comment: @MiniMax Thanks, I'm sure that's the reason. Please make your comment an answer, so I can accept it.